Can we implement a facility to safely create temporary files in C++23?
After reading a review of my own code, an answer about boost::filesystem::unique_path, another answer about unique_path and its references, documentation about tmpnam and its Linux man page, and a few other related things, I am under the impression that with C++23, we have all we need to provide a safe implementation of temporary file creation, only using the C++23 standard library.
By safe, I among others mean an implementation that would not have the known safety vulnerabilities of tmpnam and boost::filesystem::unique_path.
For instance, we could implement a class temp_file whose constructor would both generate a 128-bit random file name and open a file of that name located under std::filesystem::temp_directory_path() in exclusive mode (std::ios::noreplace), whose destructor would close the file and delete it, and whose stream member function would return a reference to the opened file's input/output stream.
Could such an implementation, assuming it is correct, be considered as a safe facility to create and use temporary files, or am I missing some important considerations, in which case, what are those considerations?

Unfortunately the standard doesn't make any guarantees about behavior of multiple threads or processes operating on the same filesystem object at the same time. None of the filesystem operations are guaranteed to behave correctly if another process or even only another threads intervenes: https://eel.is/c++draft/fs.race.behavior

So to begin with you need to rely on quality-of-implementation details in the standard library and assumptions about the underlying file system API used by the standard library implementation. Many race conditions can only be avoided if the file system operation is already atomic at the level of the operating system, so that the standard library can't provide race guarantees even if it wanted to.

Randomizing the file name with high entropy doesn't help avoiding a vulnerability because another process can list the files in the directory. It only prevents non-malicious intervention.

@user17732522, are we talking about concurrent write access to a temporary file, which leads to undefined state of the file? But how is that different from concurrent access to any other file? Why would that be more of a problem for temporary files than for other files? Also, what alternative would not have that problem? mkstemp, for instance, would not alleviate that, right?

@user17732522, in other words, I do not see how what you are referring to would make the proposed implementation any less safe than the creation and use of any other file in the filesystem.

I am saying that no file system operation is guaranteed to behave correctly when multiple threads/processes interact, in particular there is no guarantee that the operations are atomic at the file system level. For example opening the new file may internally be two steps, one creating the file and one opening the newly created file. If another process intervenes then there is no specified behavior for the standard library function. Of course, as long as the OS permits it, I expect the library implementer to still attempt to provide a race-free implementation.

And yes, it is a problem for any concurrent file operation, not only temporary files. It is just a bit worse for these, because they may be created in a directory accessible by all users.

@user17732522, for such non-trivial issues, quoting the standard, like you did, is indispensable, I think. In fact, I had read parts of the File Systems chapter, looking for some information about atomicity, but had not found it. You could consider summarizing your comments in an answer. Apart from that, this is jaw-dropping, I had not realized it was that bad.

How could this be opinion-based, when my respondents and myself have PROVED that the only possible answer to this question is "no" by quoting the relevant part of the standard?!

Maybe the people who closed this should take contact the C++ Library Working Group who thinks that "The security concerns are probably best dealt with in the next File System TS, since a full-blown proposal is needed and will likely take several years to develop". I'm sure they would be happy to hear that the TOCTTOU-issues they are trying to solve may not really exist, depending on one's opinion.

Nicol Bolas' answer, in combination with comments from user17732522, allow me to compose a self-sufficient answer, rooted in the C++ standard.

Could such an implementation, assuming it is correct, be considered as
a safe facility to create and use temporary files, or am I missing
some important considerations, in which case, what are those
considerations?

The C++23 final draft contains:

Since we can never guarantee that a separate thread or process will not access the temporary file while it is being created and accessed by the user of the facility, such a facility could not be considered as safe.
Such lack of guaranteed safety is in fact very general for C++' file streams, but, as user17732522 puts it, "it is just a bit worse for [temporary files], because they may be created in a directory accessible by all users".
When it comes to alternatives, in the C++ standard, we have tmpfile which does not expose a file name, and hence at least theoretically could be safer, at the cost of using the FILE API instead of std::fstream.
There are also OS-specific alternatives.

I think tmpfile is mostly safe to use even on the specification level, at least in recent C and C++ versions. It is specified to behave as if opening the file with x flag, which in turn is guaranteed to be an atomic operation or fail per C §7.23.5.3. There could probably still be a denial-of-service attack by guessing the names that are attempted. Neither C nor POSIX seem to guarantee that a free name is obtained atomically as well. That would require the operation to be implemented completely at the OS level. On an OS that doesn't permit the atomicity, tmpfile should always fail.

@user17732522, thanks a lot for this information. I suspected the absence of guarantee, hence my cautious wording.

I have to correct myself again. Apparently that guarantee is new in C23 and not included in any C++ version yet. Before there seems to be no guarantee of atomicity in either C or POSIX at all as far as I can tell.

C++'s filesystem API is unable to create a "safe" version of this operation.
To have a fully safe version, you need to be able to do all of the following as a single, filesystem atomic operation:

Generate a name that is unused within a directory.
Create a file with that name.
Exclusively open that file.

The standard library can do each of those individually, but the vulnerability comes from being unable to do the entire sequence as a single atomic process. So long as some other program can intervene between any of these operations, vulnerabilities exist. And C++ has no mechanism to ensure such filesystem atomicity.
If you want to do this, then for now, you must use an OS-specific library function.

I'm not entirely following this. If I construct a std::fstream from the randomized file path, with the std::ios::noreplace flag, am I not atomically doing both 2 and 3? Also, the file can be created by an attacker between 1 and 2, but then step 2/3 will fail, right? I.e. the attack does not go undetected?

@nilo: You might be doing 2 and 3 atomically. But then again, depending on the OS and file system involved, you might not. Just for one fairly well known example, before about V 2.6 or so, O_EXCL on an NFS volume from Linux wasn't atomic.

@JerryCoffin, in your "just for one fairly well known example", you seem to be referring to an officially documented limitation of the open system call, namely that O_EXCL was not supported before NFSv3 and kernel 2.6. In my opinion, on such a system, if you construct a std::fstream with the std::ios::noreplace flag and the constructed stream reports that the file is open, then there is a bug in the standard library implementation. That does not mean that the std::fstream construction is semantically non-atomic.

@nilo: Well, I suppose it's sort of moot in any case--I doubt anybody's going to be trying to port C++23 to that old a version of LInux.

Without reading the "File system race behavior" section in the C++ standard, which is easy to miss, I think a developer could reasonably expect that std::fstream::open is atomic, as it really should be, if it were not for the practical obstacles that prevent that. That makes this answer confusing I think, since it does not motivate why an implementation could have such shortcomings and still be compliant to the standard. If  such a clarification was provided, I could accept the answer.

I'd be happy to upvote this, now that I understand it better, but since it has not been updated after my downvote, I cannot, unfortunately. Apparently, StackOverflow does not think one can change their mind about an answer after some maturation time. Oh well.
